# Как найти ноль после точки и отсечь все лишнее в переменной?

Tags: java

Есть переменная double в ней число допустим 8590.330123
Как найти ноль после точки и отсечь все лишнее ? чтобы было 8590.33

Answer (score 2):

Если результат отсечения будет такой же double то ничего не получится...Ибо такова природа плавающей точки...где недавно был .30, никто не запретит поставить .29)... Подробнее о представлении плавающей точки и как ее сравнивать, можно почитать тут например http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0114/index.html ...

Как альтернативу плавающей точки можно предложить BigDecenal, там уже можно искать 0 и обрезать точность...

Если речь о текстовом представлении то тут все тривиально

```
    String numberAsString = Double.toString(number);
    int first0idx = numberAsString.indexOf('0', 
    numberAsString.indexOf('.')+1);
    numberAsString = numberAsString.substring(0, first0idx)
```

писал с телефона, но концепция должна быть ясна
хотя честно говоря пока не ясно зачем так делать

Answer (score 2):

Немного странный подход. Уточните задачу, на всякий. Есть опасения что вы выбрали не самое удачное для нее решение и просите подсказать его реализацию.

Если нужно именно то, о чем вы просите, то можно пойти в лоб:

```
public double cut(Double d){
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    //закидываем все до точки
    while(s.get(i) != '.' && i< s.length){
        sb.append(s.get(i++));
    }
    //закидываем точку
    sd.append(',');
    i++;
    //закидываем поле точки до нуля
    while(s.get(i) != '0' && i< s.length){
        sb.append(s.get(i++));
    }
    return Double.parse(sb.toString());
}
```

Даже идей нет как можно решить без представления в строке. Из-за особенностей битовой записи числа с плавающей точкой решусь предположить, что в общем случае это вообще нереально...

Answer (score 0):

А почему не сгонять дабл в стринг? Найти требуемое регуляркой, и обратно конвернуть, если требуется? Регулярочка может выглядеть так "([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)0"
Мб лишний оверхед конечно, но коротко и элегантно в коде получится